# Any way to block-copy part of picture in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm looking for analog of BitBlt functionality, which was available in WinAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out method [BitmapSource.CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms616044.aspx) (it also has one more overload).

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to copy that part to?  Another image?

In WPF, you create a Graphics context on an empty Image, then you draw the Image into this Graphics context, where you can specify parameters such as the location and width/height of the source image to draw.